# Django showing the result of a query with decimal()

Tags: python, django, string, decimal, python-unicode

Hello I have a question about the result of a query.

```
suma = Contrato.objects.aggregate(Sum('lote__Costo'))
```

The result is the sum of all the records in a column of the database.

What I can not understand exactly is the way in which I get the result of the query which is shown as follows

```
{'lote__Costo__sum': Decimal('142000.00')}
```

Is equal in the shell as in the template I wonder if there is a way to display only the result of the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value you can do

```
suma = Contrato.objects.aggregate(Sum('lote__Costo'))
decimal_val = float(suma['lote__Costo__sum'])
```

and then pass the value(decimal_val) to template